# SparkFun RedBoard PTH Kit wrongly configured hardware

Tags: arduino-ide, atmega328, ftdi, port-mapping

I have a [SparkFun RedBoard PTH Kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10908). It's not made by SparkFun, but by https://inmotion.pt (that doesn't exist anymore). I soldered it, and bought a FTDI adapter, but when I try to upload the blink example the Arduino IDE I get this error:

```
Sketch uses 1030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xa6
Problem uploading to board.  See https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/sections/360003198300 for suggestions.
```

Or if I try to reset while uploading:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x63
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfe
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xff
Problem uploading to board.  See https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/sections/360003198300 for suggestions.
```

And the link here at the end suggests the problem is wrongly configured hardware: https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/4401874331410--Error-avrdude-when-uploading

So think the problem is that when I connect the ports from the Arduino to the FTDI, two ports don't match:

[image: Schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL7T1M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Here's a picture of the soldering, though I don't think that is the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa2j5.jpg

---

I am using these drivers: https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore for the Arduino. With these settings:

[image: Driver settings]

The options only have these variants:

- 328P / 328PA
- 328 / 328A
- 328PB

But my processor says 328P-PU. I tried every one of them and they all give me the same error above.

---

Can I even use this FTDI adapter? If yes what would the setup be?

Comment: RX goes to TX, transmit to receive. one Gnd is enough and you don't need CTS

Comment: Thanks, but still having the same errors

Comment: try to manually reset the board while the IDE attempts to upload

Comment: With the reset button on board?

Comment: I tried to reset it many times but still have the same errors :( Also updated the question with new information that might help.

Comment: select variant 328P/328PA

Comment: As I said in the post I've tried every one of them and tried again now after you. All of the variants give the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work!

The problem was that I had connected the Arduino to the FTDI and not both the FTDI and the Power Brick. The [SparkFun product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10908) said that you can use like that, and the version from https://inmotion.pt that I have is identical so I though it should have worked.

Thank's a lot @jurah for you help!